# How to get particular values from JSON using powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have to get the values from JSON file for my test report purpose.
Can anyone help me how get values of `passes`, `failure` from the below JSON data.

```
    {
  "stats": {
    "suites": 2,
    "tests": 4,
    "passes": 3,
    "pending": 0,
    "failures": 0,
    "start": "2021-11-05T15:58:26.817Z",
    "end": "2021-11-05T15:59:26.701Z",
    "duration": 55162,
    "testsRegistered": 4,
    "passPercent": 75,
    "pendingPercent": 0,
    "other": 0,
    "hasOther": false,
    "skipped": 1,
    "hasSkipped": true
  },
}
```

I have tried below code, but not getting correct result

```
$json= Get-Content -Raw -Path 'C:\report.json' | ConvertFrom-Json
write-host "passes : $($json.passes)"
write-host "failures : $($json.failures)"
```

Result:

```
$json= Get-Content -Raw -Path 'C:\report.json' | ConvertFrom-Json
write-host "passes : $($json.passes)"
write-host "failures : $($json.failures)"
passes : 
failures :
```

Edit:
I have got the solution by adding below code

```
$json= Get-Content -Raw -Path 'C:\report.json' | ConvertFrom-Json
write-host "passes : $($json.stats.passes)"
write-host "failures : $($json.stats.failures)"
```

Comment: The json you show is invalid (the final comma after the closing curly bracket should not be there) or is this just part of the file? If so, please show us a sanitized version where the complete structure of the json data can be seen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution by adding below code

```
$json= Get-Content -Raw -Path 'C:\report.json' | ConvertFrom-Json
write-host "passes : $($json.stats.passes)"
write-host "failures : $($json.stats.failures)"
```

Result:

```
passes : 14
failures : 0
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$json= Get-Content -Raw -Path <jsonFile>.json | ConvertFrom-Json
//or
$json = $response | ConvertFrom-Json //if you have it from url


write-host "passes : $($json.passes)"
write-host "failures : $($json.failures)"
```